# getting my custom transmissions to work in gazebo

Tags: ros, gazebo, transmission

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm having problems getting my model to work in gazebo: when I spawn my model in gazebo, I get a segfault. I'm almost sure it's due to my custom transmissions, because the model is working when the standard pr2 simple_transmission are used.

The backtrace is available [here](http://pastebin.com/GYNmWDPj).

My model contains custom transmissions (which are almost copies of the simple_transmission.cpp, as you can see [here](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/%7Eshadowrobot/sr-ros-interface-ethercat/sr_hand_palm_edc/files/head:/sr_mechanism_model/src/).

I uploaded the generated model [here](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/%7Eshadowrobot/sr-ros-interface/trunk/view/head:/sr_hand/model/robots/shadowhand_motor.urdf).

Those transmissions are working on the real robot, but not in Gazebo.

Any ideas?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11223/getting-my-custom-transmissions-to-work-in-gazebo/) by [Ugo](https://answers.ros.org/users/72/ugo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1620 on 2011-09-15

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ugo](https://answers.ros.org/users/72/ugo/) on 2011-10-24**:
The root of the problem is that the pr2_gazebo_plugins/src/gazebo_ros_controller_manager.cpp instantiates a ''''pr2_hardware_interface::Actuator" object (line 470), and not my custom actuator (which inherits from the pr2 Actuator class). Is it not possible to have a custom actuator?

**Comment by [Ugo](https://answers.ros.org/users/72/ugo/) on 2011-09-15**:
If I comment out the call to publishMechanismStatistics() in the ControllerManager::update() function then the simulation seems to be working fine.

**Comment by [Ugo](https://answers.ros.org/users/72/ugo/) on 2011-09-15**:
It appears the problem is coming from the iteration on the actuator map in ControllerManager::publishMechanismStatistics(): the for (ActuatorMap::const_iterator it = model_.hw_->actuators_.begin(); it != model_.hw_->actuators_.end(); ++i, ++it)  returns a segfault on the 3rd element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok, I solved it by creating my own implementation of the pr2_gazebo_plugins/src/gazebo_ros_controller_manager.cpp.

This is available in the sr_gazebo_plugins package.

---

Originally posted by [Ugo](https://answers.ros.org/users/72/ugo/) with karma: 1620 on 2011-10-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0